# Using X Pixmaps with OpenGL and Haskell

Tags: opengl, haskell

I am a little bit confused on how to combine using the X11 library to generate a texture for OpenGL ( I am grabbing the pixmap area using https://github.com/reacocard/haskell-x11-xcomposite )

I guess what gets me is that the PixMap has a return type of XID which is basically a Word32 used as a pointer to the actual data but then OpenGL libraries use something different for their pointers. I know what I have to do in C,

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux:_Using_texture_from_pixmap_extension

But it seems foolish to rewrite a lot of the OpenGL and X11 stuff through FFI to make their types compatible. Is there an easier way?